# Best approach for a custom database filling in WP custom post types

Tags: mysql, wp-cron

I am currently working for a service provider that offers Windows software for inventory control. This software connects to a MySQL DB on a dedicated server. What we want to do is offer WordPress websites for them. But we want to showcase their inventory on the site.

Ultimately what I'd like to happen is for the main inventory db to be updated and then just automatically update the WP DB. When it's updated in the software, update the website automatically.

Not sure if that's a cron job or something else where the main DB is constantly monitored.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: Any way to add code to the central software? Or is there any kind of API of webhooks mechanism offered by the central db software? The best solution is probably for the central app to call your WP site every time data changes...

Comment: There is a REST API that was written. Basically everything has been done in house in PHP using MySQL. I'm hoping something would be able to be done in real time. If there's a small delay(5-15 minutes) I think that would be acceptable too, but ideally real time is the goal.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little unsure what "offer WordPress websites for them' means in terms of implementation. But here are some questions I would ask when approaching this problem:

- How tightly coupled are the systems? Is this DB and the related WP sites running on the same server?
- For the DB on a dedicated server, do you have control over the MySQL DB and / or the api that manages it?
- Do you *really* need to propagate this to WordPress? Does a JS POST request to the DB (or api) not make sense in this situation?

### Same Host

The easiest thing would be if the dedicated MySQL DB is on the same machine since authentication is already taken care of. Events that happen with the MySQL db could then be pushed to WP using some sort of wp-cli command.

### Different Hosts

If these sites are on different hosts, and if you **are** able to make changes to the dedicated server / api, then I would explore a solution where you:

1. Create an endpoint in WordPress (Rest API) which then updates the WP DB as needed.
2. Extend the dedicated server so that it issues a POST request to that endpoint

The main challenge here is authentication and security. It's not impossible but I've never really liked working with oAuth. I like this solution best though because changes are propagated out almost immediately, so you don't have differences between the two dbs.

### Different Hosts, access only to WP

If you **are not** able to make changes to the dedicated server, then I think you are left with some sort of cron solution. WordPress has a pretty good [HTTP API](https://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API) so that you don't have to do the heavy lifting of generating a full request and dealing with weird edge cases. The main drawback is that unless you are checking fairly often, there might be a difference in the number stored in the dedicated DB and the number stored in the WP DB.

Hope that helps clarify your thinking!

Comment: Thank you very much for that comment. Actually the DB's will be hosted on the same server. It's a dedicated server and it's running LAMP. Ultimately, they'd love for everything to be synced in real-time. Would that still involve the wp-cli commands?

Comment: I haven't ever done exactly what you are describing, but I think that 'Triggers' are what you want: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: In an ideal world, I would try to decouple these two DBs. So for example, if you could have the software on the windows client POST to an api and then have that api create the records in the DB as well as whatever other events are required, then you will be setting yourself up for a lot more flexibility down the line. 

By connecting directly to the DB and updating values, you are restricting yourself to what MySQL can do. Maybe MySQL can be wrangled to do that, but I certainly don't have experience doing a solution like that.